# How come only certain animals can talk?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, some animals can talk, like the toads of Mount Myōboku, Kakashi's ninja dogs, Manda, and Katsuyu. Some of them have ever used hand signs.  Yet Akamaru can't even talk. Is the ability to talk given to certain animals at random, or can they all talk when they have enough chakra or do they just simply have to learn how?

Comment: I think it was mentioned in one of the databooks, that Kakashi's Dogs can only talk because they are clever enough. I'm not sure, however.

Comment: Are you indirectly saying Akamaru isn't clever?

Comment: relevant: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/why-cant-inuzuka-clans-dogs-use-human-language/

Comment: @Vogel612 So the animals that can talk are spirts? But they can breed

Comment: @TAAPSogeking why should they not? as far as i recall they are also growing old... furthermore "spirits" is maybe the wrong expression... they are moreover the ["animal Species" representatives](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique)

Comment: @looper they are summons... not surprising they can talk. even the fckin snail can talk..